# Ubuntu 18.04 Not Detecting HDMI Port?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm running Bionic Beaver on a Dell Precision 7530, and I cannot get any of the display ports to work. No auto-detection when I plug in an HDMI nor does any other monitor appear in the display settings.

What I've tried:
I've tried switching my display manager from gdm3 to lightdm, but still the problem persists. 
I've also tried updating my kernel and graphics card driver.

Some more details:

```
user@Class-15:~$ lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
```

```
user@Class-15:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

The output of xrandr doesn't even show a disconnected HDMI port, and I haven't seen that before. What does that mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check your BIOS/UEFI settings for anything relating to graphica drivers?  You may have to enable things like the nvidia driver to enable the external display ports.

Comment: I'm booting in UEFI, and I don't think I have an nvidia graphics card. I run `hwinfo --gfxcard --short` and see only `Intel VGA compatible controller`